# PHP MySQL - Get data from checkbox

Tags: php, html, mysql, foreach, project

I am developing a website for a final year project that allows users to create questionnaires based on data stored in a database. The questions on the questionnaire are pulled from the question table which has the following fields:

```
 Questions(question_id, question_text, question_type, question_values, questionnaire_fk)
```

An example of data pulled from this would be: question text: male or female?, question type: mc (for multiple choice questions), question values: male#female (these are then exploded into an array using the #).

Thus far I have been able to create multiple choice questions by populating a select element.

I want to create a check box question format. This would allow the user to select more than one answer. I have used the following code to create the questions but I am having problems getting the answers.

```
if($row["QUESTION_TYPE"]=="cb"){

                $myArray = explode('#', $questiontype);
                echo "<input type = 'hidden' name = 'questionid[]' value = '".$questionid."'>" .$row["QUESTION_TEXT"];

                foreach($myArray as $ma){

                    echo "<input type = 'hidden' id = 'answertext' name = 'questionanswer[]' value = 'null'><input type = 'checkbox' name ='".$questionid."' value='".$ma."'>".$ma."</br>";

                }
            }
```

This code is saying: if the question type is cb(checkbox) then create an array of all the answers then echo a hidden value which is the question ID. then for each answer create a hidden holding the answer and a checkbox with the name questionid to group it.

I am having difficulty trying to retrieve the answer from the checkboxes.

With the multiple choice format I am using the following code to get the answer selected:

```
$questionanswers = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['questionanswer']);
$questionids = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST['questionid']);


foreach($questionanswers as $ind=>$ans){
$sql = "INSERT INTO ANSWERS (ANSWER_TEXT, QUESTION_FK, QUESTIONNAIRE_FK) values ('$ans', '$questionids[$ind]','$questionnaireid')";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
}
```

and the question is being created with this code:

```
    $questiontype = $row["QUESTION_VALUES"];


            if($row["QUESTION_TYPE"] == "mc"){
                    $myArray = explode('#', $questiontype);
                    echo "<input type = 'hidden'name = 'questionid[]' value = '".$questionid."'>" .$row["QUESTION_TEXT"]."<SELECT class='buttonMax' name='questionanswer[]'>";
                     foreach($myArray as $ma){
    echo '<option value="' . $ma . '">' . $ma . '</option>';
}
echo "</select> <br>";
```

Does anyone have an idea of how I could implement the checkbox question? Is it possible? I have been struggling with this for quite some time now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why are you using name='questionid[]'? Try changing it to name='questionid'

Comment: questionid[] means that he has more than one input with name questionid and it is not problem here

Comment: Leave a space betwwen `'hidden'` and `name`.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that the checkbox is **ONLY** submitted if checked!

So, if you need the value of an unchecked box you should think of a workaround like hidden inputs for all the checkboxes with corresponding values.

On the server side check the hidden inputs against the available(submitted) checkboxes.